# How to know requested module name in Django

Tags: python, django

In Django if a request is made to another module. Can we know where the request has made from through the request variable...

In the below example I have to know that the request was made from a.html ort that corresponding module

Ex:
a.html

```
<html>
<form onsubmit=/b>

</form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view code you can do something like this:

```
def my_view(request)
  referer = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '')
  if referer == 'absolute/path/to/somepage.html':
    # do something
    ...
  else:
    # do something else
    ...
```

Note that you probably want to avoid hard-coding URLs in your view code (as I've done above for the sake of simplicity, you probably want to use [`reverse()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse).